# How would I add range slider mockups in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been playing with Bootstrap 4 for a bit. I have created a range form with a slider. I would like to add mockups (little lines or numbers on top of the slider to know what you are selecting) or even a number left or right of the slider, but I am not sure how. Here is the code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="range">How many flags would you like?</label>
  <input class="form-control-range" type="range" name="flag_number" id="range" list="range">`
  </div>
```

I have tried using the datalist tag, but it doesn´t seem to work... How would one do it?

Answer (score 5):

### Bootstrap *4* real input type range will be like this

```
<input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" id="ex6" value="0">
```

and add some text for the display the value with this code :

```
<span>Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6Val"></span></span>
```

finally add the javascript function (use jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ex6').on('change', function(e){
        var id = e.target.value;            
        document.getElementById("ex6Val").innerHTML = id;
    });
    $('#ex6').change();
});
```

> Check the snippet

```js
$('#ex6').on('change', function(e) {
  var id = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById("ex6Val").innerHTML = id;
});
$('#ex6').change();
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" id="ex6" value="0">
        <span>Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6Val"></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
    <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>

// With JQuery

    $("#ex6").slider();
    $("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
        $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
    });

// Without JQuery
var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
    document.getElementById("ex6SliderVal").textContent = sliderValue;
});
```

Comment: don´t think this is what i was looking for, I want the numbers or the lines to be visible to the user